# Grails filter controller in package

Tags: grails

The project I'm working on currently uses filters for various pieces.  The filters themselves work great.  The problem I'm running into is that when specifying which controllers the filter should be executed on, I end up with a very large list.  Functionally this works fine but it ends up being ugly and somewhat unwieldy.

```
def filters =
{
        filterSomething(controller:'one|two|three|...|xyz', action:'*')
        {
            //before filter here, not important.
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to specify that the filter is only applicable for controllers in a given package or list of packages?

If there is nothing out of the box, I was thinking about tying something into the bootstrap and setting my lists that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a filter on all controllers and then check their package and then decide what you want to do. There are better and more elegant way coding this, but just to give you an idea.

```
 class MyFilters {
def grailsApplication


def filters = {
    all(controller:'*', action:'*') {
        before = {
            if (checkController(['com.package.name'],controllerName)){
            }
        }
    }
}


def searchInList(list,packageName){
    for (keyword in list) {
        if (packageName.contains(keyword)) return true
    }
    return false
}

Boolean checkController(def includePackageList,cname) {
    def dlist = grailsApplication.getArtefacts("Controller")
    def filteredList= dlist.findAll{ searchInList(includePackageList,it.getPackageName()) }
    return filteredList.contains(cname)
}
}
```

Comment: That might be worth exploring, since it looks like there is nothing out of the box.  It's at least more elegant than hard coding a giant list, especially because forgetting to add a new controller to said list results in very unintended behavior.  I'm guessing performance wouldn't be an issue, but results could be potentially cached in some manner.

Comment: sure, and there might be easier way to grab the class package name from class string, that way you wont need to iterate list the way I am doing it.

Comment: Since i don't think there is an official way of doing this, I'm going to accept the answer as it is a reasonable workaround.