# Grails controllers and inheritance/closures

Tags: grails, groovy

Grails 2.4.4 here. All of my controllers were generated using the standard `grails create-controller ...` command:

```
class FizzController {
    def index() {
        // ...
    }
}

class BuzzController {
    def index() {
        // ...
    }
}

...etc.
```

At the top of each action method, in each controller, I need to call a method `doSomething(String)`. This method needs to have access to `redirect(...)` so that it can redirect the user if need be. Ideally, I could create an abstract base controller class and have all my controllers extend it:

```
abstract class BaseController {
    void doSomething(String cmd) {
        if(cmd == 'Yee haw!') {
            redirect(controller: 'foo', action: 'baz')
            return false
        }
    }
}

class FizzController extends BaseController {
    def index() {
        String cmd = getCmdSomehow()
        doSomething(cmd)

        // ...etc.
    }
}

class BuzzController extends BaseController {
    def index() {
        String cmd = getCmdSomehow()
        doSomething(cmd)

        // ...etc.
    }
}
```

However I'm not sure Grails will allow this, since it's doing "Groovy magic" under the hood to make sure there is access to things like `redirect(...)` and `render(...)`, etc. It would also be **wonderful** if I could put all this in a closure and just have it executed implicitly (without having to call `doSomething()` at the beginning of each and every controller action.

What is my best option/solution here? Please use a concrete code example!

Comment: Why not use a filter before the controller is even called? That way you could have one filter and apply it to all controllers (or just some, or whatever your requirements are) and keep that code out of the actual controller itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Filter](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/guide/theWebLayer.html#filters) instead:

```
class ExampleFilters {

   def filters = {

      logFilter(controller: '*', action: '*') {

         before = {
         }

         after = { Map model ->
         }

         afterView = {
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Wow, exactly what I said in my comment. Nice.

Comment: Thanks @majkelo (+1) - in reality, the controllers I care about are under `grails-app/controllers/special/*` dir. Could I just specify `controller: 'special/*` for the rule attribute?

Comment: If you want to filter basing on specified package try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16220702/grails-filter-controller-in-package